# How do I know precisely what kind of "input" prop variables are there?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm from Java background and I'm trying hard to learn web language: React.
I remember in java, function is defined with set of inputs:`public static int add(int x, int y)`
However, in React there seem to be only one `(props)` and all inputs are used as `prop.x prop.y` ... etc

I'm importing the following Map component in 'kakao-map-react' package:

```
var Map = function (props) {
    var id = props.id;
    var kakao = window.kakao;
    var mapId = id ? id : 'kakao-map-react';
    var map = useMapState().map;
    var dispatch = useMapDispatch();
    React.useEffect(function () {
        if (!map) {
            var events_1 = [];
            var mapContainer = document.getElementById(mapId);
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new kakao.maps.LatLng(props.initialPosition.latitude, props.initialPosition.longitude),
                level: props.level,
            };
            var newMap_1 = new kakao.maps.Map(mapContainer, mapOptions);
            if (props.onMapLoaded) {
                props.onMapLoaded(newMap_1);
            }
            var _loop_1 = function (event_1) {
                if (props[event_1.key]) {
                    kakao.maps.event.addListener(newMap_1, event_1.event, function (mouseEvent) {
                        if (props[event_1.key]) {
                            if (event_1.hasMouseEvent) {
                                var handler = props[event_1.key](newMap_1, mouseEvent);
                                events_1.push({
                                    target: newMap_1,
                                    type: event_1.event,
                                    handler: handler,
                                });
                            }
                            else {
                                var handler = props[event_1.key](newMap_1);
                                events_1.push({
                                    target: newMap_1,
                                    type: event_1.event,
                                    handler: handler,
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            for (var _i = 0, eventsArr_1 = eventsArr; _i < eventsArr_1.length; _i++) {
                var event_1 = eventsArr_1[_i];
                _loop_1(event_1);
            }
            dispatch({
                type: 'SET_MAP',
                payload: newMap_1,
            });
            return function () {
                for (var _i = 0, events_2 = events_1; _i < events_2.length; _i++) {
                    var event_2 = events_2[_i];
                    kakao.maps.event.removeListener(event_2.target, event_2.type, event_2.handler);
                }
            };
        }
        else {
            return function () {
            };
        }
    }, []);
    /*
    * Set new center if long lat changes
    * */
    React.useEffect(function () {
        if (map) {
            map.setCenter(new kakao.maps.LatLng(props.center.latitude, props.center.longitude));
        }
    }, [
        props.center.latitude,
        props.center.longitude,
        props.center.token,
    ]);
    /*
    * Set new level if props.level changes
    * */
    React.useEffect(function () {
        if (map) {
            map.setLevel(props.level);
        }
    }, [
        props.level
    ]);
    return (React.createElement("div", { id: mapId, style: {
            height: '100%'
        } }, props.children));
};
```

In this long code, how do I know what kind of inputs(props) I need to insert?

I tried Ctrl-F 'props', but there were too many and I didn't understand which input is which:

```
props.id, props.initialPosition.latitude, props.initialPosition.longitude, props.level, props.onMapLoaded, props[event_1.key], props.center.latitude, props.center.longitude, props.center.token.
```

Thank you.

Comment: You read the documentation, or if it's implemented in typescript they're typed, or if there's a propTypes it'll list them there. Not sure what you mean by "which one is which".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a Java background myself and was surprised to see that many documentations in JavaScript world don't care about about the data types in their API references. You have two options:

1. Go through their documentation on GitHub or their official site. A well-mantained project lists their input props and which types they require.
2. You don't find that information in the documentation => You must dig through the source code and find out yourself.
3. Your IDE might be abale to help you. I use Intellij and for most packages the IDE is able to infer the types by their typescript definitions.

Comment: The API wasn't well documented, so I just created my own functions.